# Performing database opeation On Model propeties in Mvc ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
 public class CityViewModel
    {
        public List<City> GetCities { get; set; }
        public City CityDetail { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my ViewModel and i want suggestions about if its a good way to use datbase operation directly on Model property .For example

```
public List<City> GetCities
{
         get{
            return {some method for getting list from database};
            } 
         set
            {
            }
```

}

The only requirement is am gonna need that list multiple times and i don't want to keep calling same line to access that list from database everywhere.And just want whenever i create new instance of this viewmodel i can get that list automatically.So is it a good way for that?

Comment: Ideally your data access layer should map your models into viewmodels and viewmodels in models

Comment: yes but that will cause repetition of same code......to get list...

Comment: I would say avoid database call on properties. Each time this property is accessed it will get the data from db. It doesn't respect in-memory data they have. Ideally you should load Cities after `OnLoaded` any events after the vm is intialized.  By having a separate function so you could know when all are the db query is invoked

Answer (score 2):

ViewModels are pocos, they should not to be able to access the database themselves, they should not be able to access models themselves either, also its not a viewmodel's responsibility to populate itself. Ideally your data access layer should map your models into viewmodels and viewmodels in models

A `CityViewModel` should be a copy of the `City` model with some changes and the `GetCities` should be a method in your data access layer something like:-

```
public List<CityViewModel> GetCities()
{
    var cities = cityRepository.GetAll();

    List<CityViewModel> cityViewModelList = new List<CityViewModel>();

    foreach(var city in cities)
    {
        CityViewModel cityViewModel = new CityViewModel
        {
            //map your properties
        }
        cityViewModelList.Add(cityViewModel);
    }
    return cityViewModelList;
}
```

then whenever you need a list of cities you just call the `GetCities` hence no repetition of code